# ffplay duration not working?

Tags: ffmpeg

If I run command

```
ffplay -t 3 test.aac
```

it just plays the whole file, instead of 3 seconds. What command would be used to set duration of playback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `-t` option does not work on all files. I tried this command

```
ffplay -t 3 test.mkv
```

and it worked fine. As a workaround this command works for the aac file

```
ffmpeg -i out.aac -c copy -f adts -t 3 - | ffplay -autoexit -
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding `autoexit` to your command:

```
ffplay -t 3 -autoexit test.aac
```

If that doesn't work, I would suggest an alternative (mplayer):

```
mplayer -endpos 3 test.aac
```

Answer (score -1):

At Windows command prompt type:

```
c:swipl -g "thread_create((sleep(5),shell('taskkill /IM ffplay.exe')),_,[]),atomic_list_concat(['x:ffplay','VTS_01_3.VOB'],' ',Atom), shell(Atom)"  -t halt
```

This will play the VTS_O1_3.VOB file for 5 seconds, and then taskkill.exe will end the ffplay.exe,   c: and x:  are drive letters where Swi-Prolog and Ffmpeg are installed

Before typing, make sure you have Swi-Prolog installed.